# char to int (Struct and file)

Tags: c

How i can copy a `char` to an `int` to do mathematical calculations with this program in C.

I've written a file with fields `name`, `sname` and `age`.

Example of file :

```
Antonio Giannini 14
Mimmo Cava 22
Luck Santo 33
```

The code:

```
struct contact {
    char name[20];
    char sname[20];
    char age[20];
};
struct contact users[MAX];

/**
 * Read the file.
 */
void read() {
    FILE *f;
    i = 0;
    f = fopen("file.txt", "r");

    if (fopen == NULL) {
        printf("The file does not exist");
    } else {
        system("cls");
        while (!feof(f)) {
            fscanf(f,"%s", users[i].name);
            fscanf(f,"%s", users[i].sname);
            fscanf(f,"%s", users[i].age);
            i++;
        }
        fclose(f);
    }
}

/**
 * Prints the content.
 */
void stamp() {
    system("cls");
    printf("%-10s%-10s%-10s\n\n", "name", "sname", "age");
    for (j=0; j < i-1; j++) {
        printf("%-10s%-10s%-10s\n\n", users[j].name, users[j].sname, users[j].age);
    }
}
```

The code works till now but, now how I can take only the `age` to do mathematical calculations like the total or the average or the oldest and youngest?

Comment: That code works, as it is?

Comment: now i write all the code

Comment: 1) This is a mess. Format the code properly. 2) What is your **specific** question? We are not a "do my homework" site. Read [ask].

Comment: Why don't you make the `age` field in your struct an integer, and then read it as such with `fscanf(f,"%d", &utente2[i].age);`?

Comment: I try it, but not work

Comment: Note that [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong).  It's also a good idea to make sure that `i` in the loop never reaches, let alone exceeds, `MAX`.  Use: `for (i = 0; i < MAX && fscanf(f, "%s %s %s", users[i].name, users[i].sname, users[i].age) == 3; i++) ;` as your input loop.

Comment: i use it but no print the last name sname ecc of the file

Comment: @GabrieleArdei  - you can refer my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple-
int total_age = atoi(user[0].age) + atoi(user[1].age) and so on till last record.

And you can convert the integer into string by using itoa() if you want to do so.
Please use following read() function.

```
void read() {
    FILE *f;
    int total_age = 0;
    int i = 0;
    f = fopen("file.txt", "r");

    if (f == NULL) {
        printf("The file does not exist");
    } else {
        system("cls");
        while (!feof(f)) {
            fscanf(f,"%s %s %d", users[i].name,users[i].sname,users[i].age);
            total_age = total_age + (users[i].age);
            i++;
        }
        printf("Total age is %d",total_age);
        fclose(f);
    }
}
```

And change structure as follows-

```
 struct contact {
        char name[20];
        char sname[20];
        int age;
    };
```

Comment: i try it but print total:0    i don't know why don't read the age of users

Comment: @GabrieleArdei - in your code you checked fopen == NULL but you should check f==NULL.

Comment: don't understand what you mean

Comment: if (fopen == NULL) - this is wrong.. write if(f==NULL) as your file pointer is f. And after fscanf you can use atoi as mentioned above in answer to calculate total.

Comment: but with  
if (fopen == NULL) works;   now there is a way to do total without whrite int total_age = atoi(user[0].age) + atoi(user[1].age) and write for ecample total=atoi(user[i].age); (not work)

Comment: @GabrieleArdei - fopen is a function which will return value, But it is not good way to use it in comparison as used by you in your code. It can lead to undefined behavior. Please use read() as mentioned in answer.And let me know if you still have problem calculating total age.

Comment: work, the problem is how i can calculate the total automatically?  without write atoi(user[0].age)+ for each user

Comment: Use this line and remove atoi- fscanf(f,"%s %s %d", users[i].name,users[i].sname,users[i].age);

Comment: i need to take only the age, so need atoi to do matematical calculations

Comment: @GabrieleArdei Please describe in details what do you want?

Comment: i try to use ou code but the program crash                                               void read() {
    FILE *f;
    int total_age = 0;
    int i = 0;
    f = fopen("file.txt", "r");

    if (f == NULL) {
        printf("The file does not exist");
    } else {
        system("cls");
        while (!feof(f)) {
            fscanf(f,"%s %s %d", users[i].name,users[i].sname,users[i].age);
            total_age = total_age + (users[i].age);
            i++;
        }
        printf("Total age is %d",total_age);
        fclose(f);

Comment: @GabrieleArdei  Have you changed structure contact? Make age as int in it.